# Kendo UI Angular Grid - Height

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

In my `<kendo-grid></kendo-grid>` tag, i have `[height]="300"`.

If I do this without paging, it works. As soon as i turn paging on, it stops working.

I also tried `[height]="height"` with `height = 300` in my ts file.

Does anyone know of any issues that stops the height working on my grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, you cant use `[scrollable]="'none'"` if you want to set the height. Thats why it wasnt using the height i specified